# find delta, maybe by congruent triangles?

Tags: geometry

Hey there: I think this is a rather short and easy question for you. Can anyone either way please give me a hint? Would be very lovely!
I found out about almost all angles in this triangle. In my solution sheet it says that $\delta$ should be $10^\circ$. But how can I explain it or prove it? I don't have a clue how to find $\beta$ or $\delta$. Can anyone please give me a hint?

[image]

Comment: w is an angle bisector. the given angle in the left bottom corner is 70 degress, the two on the right side are 10 degrees and the one underneath the 80 is 100 degrees,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Angle subtended by a **CHORD** on the circumference is equal. (Given the fact that $w$ is the Angular bisector).

[image]

Notice here: $ \angle EBC=\angle EDC=70^0$. Now you can go on.

Comment: mh but beta is not really subtented by a chord, is it??wuld you mind to clarify what you mean by the chords?

Comment: I'm not talking about the $\beta$. But the angular bisector subtended lies on circumference!

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean )-:

Comment: ah now i really understand. If I had turned around the drawing: EC is the chord and the two angles both go to the circumference, so x=70. thank you!!!

Comment: Well, that's great! :)

Answer (score 0):

We have a small triangle, with biggest angle $100^\circ$ opposite to the drawn $100^\circ$, next to the indicated $80^\circ$. If we call $B$ and $D$ the vertices where angles $\beta$ and $\delta$ lie, then the corresponding circumferential angle of the chord $BD$ is always the same, so, it is $70^\circ$.

Then we're done: the small triangle has $100^\circ$ and $70^\circ$, so the third angle is $10^\circ$, and this is what we were looking for, because now 
$$\beta=180^\circ-(90^\circ+10^\circ)=80^\circ$$
so $\delta=10^\circ$ again.

Comment: How do you know that's $100^0$?

Comment: i dont understand whch one you mean by "the small triangle with the biggest andle 100, opposite drawn 100??

Comment: i am sorry I dont really understand that answer. would you mind. maybe i could send you an email with the picture, so you could write into it?thank you

Answer (score -1):

Given: 
A
C
‾
AC
  and 
B
D
‾
BD
  bisect each other.

Prove: 
B
C
‾
≅
A
D
‾
BC
 ≅ 
AD
 .

Note: quadrilateral properties are not permitted in this proof.
Step    Statement   Reason
1
A
C
‾
AC
  and 
B
D
‾
BD
  bisect each other
Given
try 
Type of Statement
A
B
C
D
E
Note: 
A
C
‾
AC
  and 
B
D
‾
BD
  are segments.

You must answer all questions above in order to submit.